# Move files into same name folder through R

Tags: r

> I have a folder that contains different sample csv files and same name folders:

```
files name:-
sample_190612.csv
sample_729924.csv  
sample_729794.csv 
sample_780414.csv
sample_780388.csv 
................
............
folders:-
sample_190612
sample_729924
sample_729794 
sample_780414
sample_780388
............
...............
```

> How to move these files into it file's name folder
>
> Expected output: Folder contains file:-

```
  Folder:-     sample_190612 
  File:        sample_190612.csv


  Folder:-     sample_729924  
  file:        sample_729924 .csv


  Folder:-    sample_780414 
  file:       sample_780414.csv
```

Comment: what is the type of input file ?

Comment: Does second column indicate existing files in a different directory? And commas indicate separate files?

Comment: No, these are samples and genes

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you want to do.
But the code below can separate strings "AC###" by commas (as Parfait asked),
and create folders using the first column, 
and save files using the "AC###" string.

```
dfFiles = data.frame(matrix(data = c(
  "sample_190612", "FSTL1",
  "sample_729924", "AC002072.1",
  "sample_729924", "AC002070.1,AC004812.1",
  "sample_729794", "ANKRD12,AP000897.1,AP005118.1,AP005227.1",
  "sample_780414", "AC002464.1,AIM1,AK9,AL021326.",
  "sample_780414", "AC002464.4",
  "sample_780414", "AIM2",
  "sample_780388",  "ATP10A,MIR4715"
), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE  ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

colnames(dfFiles) = c("sample", "gene")
# dfFiles

lsSplit = strsplit(x = dfFiles$gene, split = ",")

# create a parent folder
myParent = "sampleParent"
if(!dir.exists(myParent)){dir.create(myParent)}

# create sub folders
for(ctSample in seq_len(nrow(dfFiles))){
  thisSample = dfFiles$sample[ctSample]
  thisPath = paste0(myParent, "/", thisSample)
  if(!dir.exists(thisPath)){dir.create(thisPath)}
  # save files
  for(ctSplit in seq_len(length(lsSplit[[ctSample]]))){
    thisSplit = lsSplit[[ctSample]][ctSplit]
    write.csv(x = 0, file = paste0(thisPath, "/", thisSplit, ".csv"))
  }
}
```

This below is the result image.

[image]